# How to replace a link text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML code and I want to replace something by JavaScript.

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="childdiv">
        <a href="www.abc.com" rel="prev">Old Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to change "Old Text" to another like "New Text".

Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried document.getElementsByClassName('childdiv a').text('new text'); but failed.

Comment: Please let me know if you know any Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to locate your element element inside the DOM , it would be better to use `class` or/and `id` propreties.

But in case if you are not allowed to edit the DOM you have to find a way to find the required element like crossing parents that do have an `id` or a `class`.

1. Get first element with this class   `childdiv`.
2. Get first `a` tag inside the above found element .
3. Set innerHTML for the found element to the required value exp: `New Text`.

#### Javascript (as you asked for)

```html
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="childdiv">
        <a href="www.abc.com" rel="prev">Old Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("childdiv")[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML="New Text";

</script>
```

#### Jquery (same logic as above)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".childdiv a").text("New Text");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="childdiv">
        <a href="www.abc.com" rel="prev">Old Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply use `document.getElementById("my-link").innerHTML = "New Text"`, but you should put an `id` attribute to your `<a>` tag like so:

```
<a id="my-link" href="www.abc.com" rel="prev">
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or, if you don't want to edit anything on your original HTML (bad practice):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML = "New Text";
```

Comment: @IftekHar Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can access such DOM object by using

```
document.getElementsByClassName("childdiv")[0].childNodes[1].textContent="Updated Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your issue but I have tried this and it's working...

```
<div class="maindiv">
   <div class="childdiv">
      <a href="www.abc.com" class="link" rel="prev">Old Text</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery

```
$(".link").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).text("New Text");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/294m3my6/

If you want JavaScript

```
<div class="maindiv">
   <div class="childdiv">
      <a href="www.abc.com" id="link" rel="prev">Old Text</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And JS

```
function Action(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = "Next Text";
}

document.getElementById('link').addEventListener(
    'click', Action, false
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ep3v5u0k/

Comment: That's **jQuery**.

Answer (score 0):

@Amani has solve my problem. It is what I wanted.

```
<div class="maindiv">
<div class="childdiv">
    <a href="www.abc.com" rel="prev">Old Text</a>
</div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("childdiv")[0].getElementsByTagName('a') [0].innerHTML="New Text";
```

Thanks you so much all of you specially Amani.